# How can I avoid that $owner_password is set?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf

In your ([documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html)) there is only one possibility for $owner_password and that is that a password is always set as I understand.

Either I set a password myself or if I omit it/set it to zero then mpdf generates a password itself.

This is a big problem for us because we use your Libary to create invoices and automated invoicing systems from our customers think that there is a password problem.

In the following screenshot you can see that the "Security Method" is set to Password Security and "Permissions Password" is set to Yes.

The "Security Method" must be set to No Security and this only happens if this "Permissions Password" is not set.

[image: PDF properties (Screenshot)]

We use the following code to set the protection:

```
$mpdf->SetProtection(array('print','copy','modify','annot-forms','fill-forms','extract','assemble','print-highres'));
```

I hope you can help us with our problem and happy holidays :)

Comment: We're not mpdf, we're stackoverflow. It's not _our_ documentation, or _our_ library. We're some random volunteers who are members of this site. Coincidentally, some may also contribute to the mpdf project, but you may or may not find that to be the case. Take the [tour] to understand what stackoverflow is - it's not a bug tracker for open-source projects, that's for sure. mpdf [has its own issue tracker](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues).

Comment: We can probably help you with issues in your general usage of mpdf - e.g. setting the right options, integration, etc etc. But if you think you've found an internal bug, the issue tracker is almost certainly a better place to post it. They also suggest to use the github [discussions](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/discussions) area.

Comment: Is your question "How do I enable restrictions on a PDF without a password"? If so, this is not possible in native PDF, the passwords are part of the encryption system which is used for restrictions. There are third parties that do enable this, but they require the PDF to be viewed in their software.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.